# Ubuntu 15.10 minimal installation issues

Tags: networking, live-usb, 15.10, ubuntu-minimal

Followed [the instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick#Unetbootin-1) to create a bootable, external USB drive using *Unetbootin* and the mini.iso. Then referred the steps in [another blog](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/minimal) for a command-line installation. Halfway through the process, installer prompts to restart. After that restart, two problems are encountered:

1. The system did not boot without the USB drive. 'boot' flag on the primary partition of /dev/sda was missing, and fixed using parted. Still did not help. Curiously, when system boots with the USB drive, it is no more prompting for the OS installation, but proceeds to boot Ubuntu on /dev/sda.
2. None of the network interfaces are up. `ifconfig` shows only the loopback interface lo. This issue is not seen if the installation is tried normally, ***not*** the Command line setup.

I have a fix for the first issue: `grub-install /dev/sda`. **Looks like there is some issue in the installation setup** that incorrectly overwrites the MBR on the USB drive, instead of writing it to the disk /dev/sda.

Anyone else experienced this?